# Python: if error raised I want to stay in script

Tags: python

I am doing some practice problems from online with python and I have a question about how to stay in a script if an error is raised. For example, I want to read in values from prompt and compare them to a set integer value inside the script. The only problem is that when someone enters something other than a number 'int(value)' (ex. value = 'fs') raises an error and exits the script. I want to have it so if this happens I stay inside the script and ask for another value to be entered at the prompt.

Comment: Research before asking: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 26):

Use [`try/except`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
...         break
...     except ValueError:
...         print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
...
```

Answer (score 11):

```
success = false
while not success:
    try:
        value = raw_input('please enter an integer')
        int(value)
        success = true
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 5):

How about catching it?

```
try:
    a = int('aaa')
except ValueError:
    print('Still working')
```

Answer (score 2):

Ah, you just want to catch the error (as long as it isn't final): see http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html for details? Or are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 1):

for this, you use `try... except` as explained in the [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Read up on the `try:` `except:` idiom [here](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html)

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing it as a function you can do it as a decorator of the function

```
def retry(func):
    def wrapper(*args,**kwargs):
        while True:
            try:
                return func(*args,**kwargs)
                
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"{e} running again") # or simply pass
    return wrapper

@retry 
def myfunction():
   if badthinghappend:
     raise Error
   return something
```